# Adding tangentially related tags just for the purpose of more viewers

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670533/setting-environment-variables-for-scons-to-use-globally-on-my-system) concerning the scons build system. Looking at the activity of that tag, I worry that few people will see the question, as the tag does not have a large following. I suspect that even if there are many people familiar with scons, they don't keep up with the questions about it, simply because there aren't many.  The question does mention C++, which is a high traffic tag. And as I was editing, the C++ tag was suggested to me.  I didn't add it though, because my question requires no C++ expertise.

What do you suggest I do in situations like this?  Is it okay to add the C++ tag, just for the purpose of more views, even though it is only tangentially related to my question? Or should I just wait it out and hope for the best, and add a bounty when the question is eligible?

Comment: I think tangential is fine. I've done a similar thing with WAF. The question will lead balloon otherwise, even though I still had one lead balloon even WITH language tags. Also, I think it facilitates a type of subject discovery for answerers who only peruse language tags.